# Making hibernate ignore normal get methods

Tags: hibernate, methods, mapping, field

I have an application that was mapped using fields, so after reading about it I have decied to move to methods. However now I have a problem where in one of my abstract class that has method getFullName show an error that says

Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.bomahabo.flow.domain.project.shot.ShotComponent column: fullName (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

the things is that this methods is not mapped and it shouldnt be since it is a normal method. Which brings me to another thing. If I use methods as mapping does that mean that hibernate will attempt to map any get method that returns a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set that field as transient. If you are using attributes then you are looking for @Transient

Comment: is there a way to say it to hibernate to ignore the fields that are not mapped? I have a lot of methods and I would like to avoid putting annotation @Transient an all of them if possible

Comment: I have no idea on what your tech stack looks like neither if you are using annotations, hibernate mapping files or something else. If you are using annotations then it's a no brainer. the @Transient is exactly what you need. If you have loads of properties and methods that are not saved in the database then consider refactoring your code to extract these methods in a Utility class or a some business logic service